# I can't send user mail on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi, postfix-mta

I almost give up what is wrong.
I've setup web server by using nginx.
But I can't send user mail on WordPress.
When I create user or reset password, WordPress must stop.

The environment is bellow.
`Ubuntu0.16.04.1`
`Nginx 1.12.1`
`PHP 7.0.1`
`FPM/FastCGI`

`postfix 3.1.0`
(I can send mail by 'mail' command.)

`WordPress 4.4.2`

Nginx Erro log is bellow----

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/cms/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/cms/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 275" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: {global_ip}, server: {domain},
>   request: "POST /cms/wp-admin/user-edit.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "{host_name}",
>   referrer:
>   "/cms/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=2&wp_http_referer=%2Fcms%2Fwp-admin%2Fusers.php"

---

Any help or hint?

Comment: how to send mail? please update your question with sending code

Comment: Looks like your hosting provider has disabled PHPMailer.  If you can re-install WordPress that might work, otherwise you'll need to get in touch with them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didin't use code. WordPress stop when just creating user on admin page.

Comment: @stevenkellow Thank you for your hint.I'll check it.

Comment: Thanks every one.It solved. I use "sudo apt get wordpress",

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one.It was solved.

When I install WordPress ,I've used "sudo apt get wordpress",and copy them to html root.
I don't know why ,(I might not use 'cp' command with sudo )
'class-phpmailer.php' and 'class-phpmailer.php' were not moved properly.

So that when the system use wp_mail() function , the WordPress was stop.
That's all.Thanks a lot!